# Python Pandas extract value from dataframe based on minimum index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I've got a df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"price":[1.1,66.3,11,15.2,1.1], 
                   "qty":[14,2,1,10,1],
                   "c_h":['cheese','ham','ham','cheese','ham'],
                   "qual":['good','good','bad','good','bad']})
```

The df looks like this when printed:

```
      c_h   price  qty  qual
0  cheese     1.1   14  good
1     ham    66.3    2  good
2     ham    11.0    1   bad
3  cheese    15.2   10  good
4     ham     1.1    1   bad
```

I'm trying to return a `price` of `'c_h'=='ham' and 'qual=='bad'` on the minimum index value from a the df.  The minimum index is the lowest numerical value for index currently `[0,1,2,...]`in which that criteria is met

In this example, the minimum index sought would be 2 and the returned price would be 11.0.

Note: I'm working mostly with `pandas` but I could also use `numpy`.

I thought it'd be something like

```
df[df['c_h']=='ham' and 'qual'=='bad'].min()[index]
```

but that's not working.

Comment: what do you mean by "the minimum index"???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I updated the description. "The minimum index is the lowest index in which that criteria is met."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
>>> df[(df.c_h == 'ham') & (df.qual == 'bad')].index.min()
2
```

But if you don't just want the index, you can use the indexers:

```
>>> df.loc[(df.c_h == 'ham') & (df.qual == 'bad'), 'price'].iloc[0]
11.0
>>> df.loc[(df.c_h == 'ham') & (df.qual == 'bad'), 'price'].iloc[[0]]
2    11.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Note, the above takes the *first* index, not the *lowest* index. If you index is a normal, int-range index, then these will be equivalent.

However, if it isn't:

```
>>> df.index = [3,1,2,4,0]
>>> df
      c_h  price  qty  qual
3  cheese    1.1   14  good
1     ham   66.3    2  good
2     ham   11.0    1   bad
4  cheese   15.2   10  good
0     ham    1.1    1   bad
>>> df.loc[(df.c_h == 'ham') & (df.qual == 'bad'), 'price']
2    11.0
0     1.1
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Then get the *first* the same way:

```
>>> df.loc[(df.c_h == 'ham') & (df.qual == 'bad'), 'price'].iloc[[0]]
2    11.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

But the *lowest* would require something to the effect of:

```
>>> df.loc[(df.c_h == 'ham') & (df.qual == 'bad'), 'price'].sort_index().iloc[[0]]
0    1.1
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: close : I was expecting to see the `price` column get referenced but maybe I'll need to use `loc` in an additional step?

Comment: The index value is treated like a time stamp such that the lowest index value is the most recent.  for `df.loc[(df.c_h == 'ham') & (df.qual == 'bad'), 'price'].iloc[[0]]` the `iloc[[0]]` part returns the min index?

Comment: @jmb277 i've added various approaches to the answer, depending on exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You coule use the ‘pandas.DataFrame.query()‘ method :

```
df.query("col1 == value1 and col2==value2").sort_index()["target_column"].iloc[0]
```